# Printing form gives me blank page

Tags: c#, winforms

Using the code example from MSDN on how to print a windows form, I have the altered mine to bring up the printer options first and then print, but I keep receiving a blank page. Using `CopyFromScreen`, I am giving the coordinates of the forms source X & Y, but for the destination I have tried `0` as well as `this.Location.X & Y`.  Is there another way to capture the image?

```
private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CaptureScreen();

        printDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;

        printDialog1.ShowHelp = true;

        printDialog1.Document = printDoc1;

        DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDoc1.Print();
        }
    }        

 private void CaptureScreen()
    {
        Graphics myGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        Size s = this.Size;
        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
    }

void printDoc1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks to be fine the only thing that I notice that I don't see is an Instance of the `PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();` does it print everything after the blank page..?

Comment: Yes, I do have that.  Forgot to post.  private PrintDocument printDoc1 = new PrintDocument();

Comment: Document whether your form has the Opacity or TransparencyKey property set.

Comment: I have nothing set for that.  Ive never heard of it until now.

Comment: Might not make a difference either but do you ever assign a name to the print document..? for example `printDoc1.DocumentName = MyScrenPrint` for example I would also do the if condition check on this line 
`if(printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){printDoc1.Print();}`

Comment: Still priting a blank page.

Comment: Please don't post answers in the question.  Post your own answer in the box provided below.